# How do I get a proper subshell in mc's mcedit?

Tags: shell, midnight-commander

I can use the shell from mc when pressing <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> and when using Debian, I can also use that shortcut from `mcedit`.

However, in Ubuntu, this will only show the shell but I cannot enter anything.